# Why does my android studio Terminal not recognize flutter?

Tags: flutter, macos, android-studio, terminal, fish

I open my terminal on MacOS where everything works. I run `which fish`, and I set the Shell path in Android Stuido to the output: `/opt/homebrew/bin/fish`

[image]

If I then run `which flutter` in there, it doesn't work.
The funky thing is, that if I switch to zsh and then call fish from the path defined in Shell path in the Android Studio settings as described above, it works?

[image]

I don't know why flutter is in `flutter/bin//flutter`, that looks a bit odd to me, but ... it works? So unless that's a problem I don't think it matters. Anyways:

There are some other oddities. For example if I run `which fish` in the 'startup terminal' it gives me a [1] error, but if I then swith to zsh and open fish with the path above, it works. Other things, like git, pod and all normal commands, work. I have had this problem for a few days, as such there have been enough Mac and Android Studio restarts. I am not entirely sure why this is happening but it means I think something is going wrong on startup. I am not sure what though that may be though. I don't know what other info to provide, this is all that I found out. Thanks for any help!

Comment: just because 2 problems have the same solution doens't make them the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Now this is interesting. While <strike>playing around with the settings</strike> strategically trial-and-erroring the terminal settings I found out that un-checkmarking the `shell integration` checkmark, fixes all of the issues above. If anyone else has this issue, try it. But if someone can explain why exactly this happened, I'd be interested to know.

[image]